# Removing a UIView from its superView and expanding its frame to full screen

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have an object that is a subclass of UIView that can be added to a view hierarchy as a subView.  I want to be able to remove the UIView from its superView and add it as a subView of the main window and then expand to full screen.

Something along the lines of:

```
// Remove from superView and add to mainWindow
[self retain];
[self removeFromSuperView];
[mainWindow addSubView:self];

// Animate to full screen
[UIView beginAnimations:@"expandToFullScreen" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
self.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self release];
```

Firstly am I on the right lines?  Secondly, is there an easily way for the object to get a pointer to the mainWindow?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: to answer your second question: UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use window property of the view

```
self.window
```

Comment: Cheers Andriy, missed that one completely.  It also makes the removing from superView very easy as the view can only have one super view.  So simply [self.window addSubView:self] seems to do the trick without the need for the retain and removeFromSuperView.  Regards Dave.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good. But you might want to convert the view's frame from its superview coordinate system to the window's coordinate system, before beginning the animation. Otherwise the animation will not be smooth.

Comment: Hi Kris, is there a way of getting the co-ordinates of a view within a view hierarchy relative to the main window rather than its superView?  The frame property is relative to the parent view, does that mean I'd have to traverse up the tree and calculate the co-orninates manually?

Comment: UIView has a convenience method for that conversion: [UIView convertRect:toView:]  (the main window is also a view) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Kris, very helpful.  Have voted up your comments. Dave